# what is the purpose of openhelper in android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

instead of  sqlite openhelper we can able to create,delete,update database in android then what is the purpose of sqlite openhelper can any body explain please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit is that you don't have to determine in your code when exactly to create or update the database; Android will call the methods which you have defined at the correct moment. It's clearest on the update: if you simply change the version of your database from 1 to 2, Android will call the onUpdate method at the appropriate time, which may be difficult for you to know if you had to code it yourself.

Or from the Javadoc:

> This class makes it easy for
>   ContentProvider implementations to
>   defer opening and upgrading the
>   database until first use, to avoid
>   blocking application startup with
>   long-running database upgrades.